# Magit how to cancel running git process

Tags: magit, git

In Magit, how can I cancel a git process that is taking too long?

If I did something like `git push` from a terminal, I could press control-C to cancel. How can I do this from Magit?

Comment: `M-x list-processes`, select the process to be killed (with the cursor or the mouse), press the letter `d` to delete the process at point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `M-x magit-process-kill` in the Magit process buffer (`$`, or `M-x magit-process-buffer` jumps to process buffer for the current repository).

```
magit-process-kill is an interactive Lisp closure in `magit-process.el'.

(magit-process-kill)

Kill the process at point.
```

Comment: In Magit's process buffer, `magit-process-kill` is bound to `k`.

Answer (score 5):

Type $ in the Magit Status buffer to open Magit's process buffer , and then kill this buffer.  Emacs will ask you whether to kill the process.

Comment: Or `M-: (kill-process)` to do so without killing the buffer. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/10627289

Comment: @phils Ah, nice, I didn't know that.

Comment: There is also `magit-process-kill`, could also be useful

Comment: Although this does work, I don't want to lose my history of underlying git commands.

Comment: @npostavs I think your comment is the best answer. If you move it to an answer then I will accept it :). Thanks everyone for the quick responses!